# command line compiler add version number to EXE

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to add an parameter to vbc.exe witch add a version number to your assembly? It seemed only possible using visual studio

Comment: Version in compiled assembly is defined by assemblyInfo file in you vbproj

Comment: you can set version in assembly.info before build

Comment: But how do I let vbc.exe know that there is an assembly.info without the project file?